# Alterar dinamicamente a cor de texto com base em uma cor de fundo

Tags: javascript, css, css3

Galera, tenho esse código em que ele me gera uma especie de tema https://jsfiddle.net/jpcaja7t/18/ e gostaria de aplicar esse outro código nele para que o texto entre em contraste com o bg, Como posso fazer isso pois meu bg e a cor do texto são aleatorios?

Porém gostaria de que o código me desse varias core de contraste e não somente uma.

**Código para deixar o texto em contraste**

```
var rgb = $('#content').css('backgroundColor');
var colors = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
var brightness = 1;

var r = colors[1];
var g = colors[2];
var b = colors[3];

var ir = Math.floor((255-r)*brightness);
var ig = Math.floor((255-g)*brightness);
var ib = Math.floor((255-b)*brightness);

$('#content').css('color', 'rgb('+ir+','+ig+','+ib+')');
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode determinar a distância das cores a aplicar um brilho diferente de acordo com a tolerância:

```js
function isNeighborColor(color1, color2, tolerance) {
   // Função tirada da resposta:
   // https://stackoverflow.com/a/11506531/3497987
   // Se foi útil para você vá lá e de um voto a favor.
    if(tolerance == undefined) {
        tolerance = 32;
    }

    return Math.abs(color1.r - color2.r) <= tolerance
        && Math.abs(color1.g - color2.g) <= tolerance
        && Math.abs(color1.b - color2.b) <= tolerance;
}

var color = $('#test').css('backgroundColor');
var colors = color.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);

var rgb = {
    r: colors[1],
    g: colors[2],
    b: colors[3]
}

function GenerateRGB(rgb, brightness){
    var brightness = brightness == undefined ? 1 : brightness;
    var ir = Math.floor((255-rgb.r)*brightness);
    var ig = Math.floor((255-rgb.g)*brightness);
    var ib = Math.floor((255-rgb.b)*brightness);
    
    return {r: ir, g: ig, b: ib};
}

var nrgb = GenerateRGB(rgb, 1);
console.log(rgb, nrgb, isNeighborColor(rgb, nrgb, 165));

$('#test').css('color', 'rgb('+nrgb.r+','+nrgb.g+','+nrgb.b+')');

if (isNeighborColor(rgb, nrgb, 165))
    nrgb = GenerateRGB(rgb, 1.2);

$('#test2').css('color', 'rgb('+nrgb.r+','+nrgb.g+','+nrgb.b+')');
```

```css
#test, #test2 {
 background-color: #422DAD;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">Some text</div>
<br>
<div id="test2">Some other text</div>
```

---

#### Obsoleto

Conforme [essa resposta em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12043228/3497987) fiz o seguinte exemplo:

```js
function CheckColor(c){
  // Código dessa função foi tirado da resposta
  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/12043228/3497987
    var c = c.replace('#', '');  // strip # 
    var rgb = parseInt(c, 16);   // convert rrggbb to decimal
    var r = (rgb >> 16) & 0xff;  // extract red
    var g = (rgb >>  8) & 0xff;  // extract green
    var b = (rgb >>  0) & 0xff;  // extract blue
    
    var luma = 0.2126 * r + 0.7152 * g + 0.0722 * b; // per ITU-R BT.709
    
  // Fiz alguns testes e identifique que o fator 160 é uma boa referência
  // Altere como desejar
  return (luma < 160);
}

// Função aleatorio e CorAleatoria
// foram usados códigos desse link
// http://www.criarweb.com/artigos/gerar-cor-aleatoria-javascript.html

function aleatorio(inferior,superior){ 
   numPossibilidades = superior - inferior;
   aleat = Math.random() * numPossibilidades;
   aleat = Math.floor(aleat);
   return parseInt(inferior) + aleat;
} 

function CorAleatoria(){ 
   hexadecimal = new Array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F");
   cor_aleatoria = "#";
   for (i=0;i<6;i++){ 
      posarray = aleatorio(0,hexadecimal.length);
      cor_aleatoria += hexadecimal[posarray];
   } 
   return cor_aleatoria ;
} 

// Conversão para Hexadecimal
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/1740716/3497987
var hexDigits = new Array
        ("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f"); 

//Function to convert hex format to a rgb color
function rgb2hex(rgb) {
 rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
 return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
}

function hex(x) {
  return isNaN(x) ? "00" : hexDigits[(x - x % 16) / 16] + hexDigits[x % 16];
 }

// Aplica cor aleatória
var cor = CorAleatoria();
document.body.style.backgroundColor = cor;


// Verifica a cor de fundo e aplica cor da fonte
var corAleatoria = rgb2hex( document.body.style.backgroundColor );

document.body.style.color = CheckColor(corAleatoria) ? '#fff' : '#000' ;
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis cupiditate adipisci reprehenderit ea iure laborum voluptate deserunt rerum ad placeat recusandae delectus nulla veritatis iste maxime ipsa odio sit vel.</p>
```

Execute o código várias vezes para testar diversas cores.

Comment: Então mas o que eu quero é que a cor da fonte mude de acordo com o contraste do fundo, o bg do que passei ele funciona normal, só não quero que em um bg vermelho caia uma font rosa por exemplo.

Comment: eu tirei por base nesse código onde o texto entra em contraste com o bg http://jsfiddle.net/2VTnZ/2/

Comment: não entendi o atualize a resposta, e como que eu consigo implementar o código que me passou no meu tema aleatório? pq esse é o grande problema, em todos os modelos eles funcionam porém no que eu fiz que gera aleatório o tema não funciona

Comment: No trecho da cor onde é gerada a segunda cor você compara a tolerância `if (isNeighborColor(rgb, nrgb, 165))` e a tolerância for menor que `165` você gera novamente `nrgb = GenerateRGB(rgb, 1.2);` esse é a regra que precisa implementar no seu gerador de cor @VictorSaul

Comment: e com esse código como que eu faço para ele ler as cores que eu botei e não só preto e branco?

Answer (score 2):

Usando uma biblioteca muito boa para tratamento de cor chamado [chroma.js](http://gka.github.io/chroma.js/) você pode facilmente manipular a cor do background do dom e aplicá-lo na estilo da color do texto.

Segue uma função que retorna no padrão `rgba` o valor da cor do background

```
function GetBG(e) {
    var v = null;
    if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) {
        var cs = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(e, null);
        if (cs && cs.getPropertyValue) v = cs.getPropertyValue('background-color');
    }
    if (!v && e.currentStyle) v = e.currentStyle['backgroundColor'];
    return v;
};
```

Com o dado da cor do background você pode manipulá-la facilmente:

```
function calculaBG(dom) {
    var $o = chroma(GetBG(dom));
    if ($o.luminance() < 0.5) return $o.brighten(2);
    else return $o.darken(2);
}
```

Função que calcula a cor, [`luminance`](http://gka.github.io/chroma.js/#color-luminance) varia entre 0 para preto e 1 para branco, no caso acima se a luminância for menor que 50% aplica um clarear ([`brighten`](http://gka.github.io/chroma.js/#color-darken-brighten)) em relação a cor do background, se for maior que 50% ele aplica escurecer ([`darken`](http://gka.github.io/chroma.js/#color-darken-brighten)) a cor do background.

Segue exemplo no [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a41gmfmo/)

Comment: vlw cara é quase isso, só gostaria de que o contraste fosse se o fundo for escuro a font fique clara e vice-versa

Comment: Mas qual cor? se for a cor do background o `if ($o.luminance() < 0.5) return $o.brighten(2) else return $o.darken(2)` já faz isso, vc pode aumentar de 2 pra 3 (`$o.brighten(3)` e `$o.darken(2)`) pra ficar mais claro e mais escuro.

Comment: Desculpe minha ignorância mas copiei seu código para o meu local e não esta funcionando, como eu deveria colocar, em uma tag <script> ou linkar o js dele?

Comment: Ah e mais uma coisa @Leandro Amorim sabe se teria como fazer esse resultado do contraste porém com cores aleatórias como era o meu arquivo?

Comment: Sim vc tem que adicionar o script que pode ser baixado no endereço [aqui](https://gka.github.io/chroma.js/vendor/chroma-js/chroma.min.js), sobre a segunda pergunta, faça uma nova pergunta detalhando o que vc quer, pois, responder por aqui é muito complicado.

Comment: percebi olhando que no código do chroma.js ele tem uma variedade de cores hexa, porém ele só retorna uma cor para cada fundo, teria como ele retornar mais de uma cor usando a base dele?

Comment: @VictorSaul partindo das ideias que recebeste nas respostas tens de "brincar" com o código, testar e adaptar para fazer o que precisas. Lembra-te que se tiveres dúvidas novas o melhor é colocar noutra pergunta. Quanto mais isolares o problema em cada pergunta mais fácil será encontrares resposta ao problema colocado.